# Safe conversion of Float to Int?

Tags: swift, type-conversion, numbers

Float to Int conversion is documented to be a simple as:

```
let i = Int(x)
```

However this alone is unsafe, as a Swift app will crash if x is too big to fit in an integer, or is a NaN of some kind.

So what is the simplest, yet safe way to convert the unknown contents of a Float or Double to an Int (Int32, UInt16, etc.), e.g. without risking a crash?  Is there an Int?() type?  Or equivalent "if let" statement?

Comment: If a float exceeds `Int.max`, what value are you expecting? `nil` or `Int.max`?

Comment: Either Int.min or nil is safer than aborting the app.

Comment: @ielyamani `nil` would be a better design. That leaves the interpretation up to the consumer. If they want `Int.max`, the can easily just `?? Int.max`, but this gives them the ability to know when the number is out of range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Int(exactly:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2804478-init) might be what you are looking for:

> Creates an integer from the given floating-point value, if it can be represented exactly.
>
> If the value passed as source is not representable exactly, the result is nil.

Example:

```
let x = 123e20
if let i = Int(exactly: x) {
    print(i)
} else {
    print("not representable")
}
```

This will also fail if the floating point number is not integral, so you might want to round it before the conversion:

```
let x = 12.3
if let i = Int(exactly: x.rounded(.towardZero)) {
    print(i)
}
```

Rounding towards zero is what `Int(x)` would do, you can pick your desired rounding mode.

Answer (score 3):

Martin R's answer shows the right way, but I'm still writing this in order to teach what's going on "under the hood."

The limited precision of `Double` means that only that at the magnitude of `Int64.max` and `Int64.min`, `Double` representations are only available for every `4,096` Integers. As a result, there are a set of integers, which are valid and within range of `Int64`, which after (lossy) conversion to Double, end up rounded to a magnitude no longer representable as `Int64`. To account for these values, we need to ensure we only accept the range `Double(Self.min).nextUp ... Double(Self.max).nextDown`, rather than `Double(Self.min)... Double(Self.max)`

```
Int.min                 -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 
Float(Int.min)          -9,223,372,036,854,780,000 lower than Int.min by 4096, thus not representable by Int
Float(Int.min).nextUp   -9,223,371,487,098,960,000 greater than Int.min by 549,755,820,032, thus representable by Int
Int.max                 +9,223,372,036,854,775,807  
Float(Int.max)          +9,223,372,036,854,780,000 greater than Int.max by 4096, thus not representable by Int
Float(Int.max).nextDown +9,223,371,487,098,960,000 lower than Int.max by 549,755,820,032, thus representable by Int
```

Here's what that looks like, in action

```
import Foundation

extension FixedWidthInteger {
    static var representableDoubles: ClosedRange<Double> {
        return Double(Self.min).nextUp ... Double(Self.max).nextDown
    }

    init?(safelyFromDouble d: Double) {
        guard Self.representableDoubles.contains(d) else { return nil }
        self.init(d)
    }
}

func formatDecimal(_ d: Double) -> String{
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    numberFormatter.positivePrefix = "+"
    return numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: d))!
}

let testCases: [Double] = [
    Double.nan,
    -Double.nan,
    Double.signalingNaN,
    -Double.signalingNaN,

    Double.infinity,
    Double(Int.max),
    Double(Int.max).nextDown,
    +1,
    +0.6,
    +0.5,
    +0.4,
    +0,
    -0,
    -0.4,
    -0.5,
    -0.6,
    -1,
    -1.5,
    Double(Int.min).nextUp,
    Double(Int.min),
    -Double.infinity,
]

for d in testCases {
    print("Double: \(formatDecimal(d)), as Int: \(Int(safelyFromDouble: d)as Any)")
}
```

which prints:

```
Double: NaN, as Int: nil
Double: NaN, as Int: nil
Double: NaN, as Int: nil
Double: NaN, as Int: nil
Double: +∞, as Int: nil
Double: +9,223,372,036,854,780,000, as Int: nil
Double: +9,223,372,036,854,770,000, as Int: Optional(9223372036854774784)
Double: +1, as Int: Optional(1)
Double: +0.6, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: +0.5, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: +0.4, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: +0, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: +0, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: -0.4, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: -0.5, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: -0.6, as Int: Optional(0)
Double: -1, as Int: Optional(-1)
Double: -1.5, as Int: Optional(-1)
Double: -9,223,372,036,854,770,000, as Int: Optional(-9223372036854774784)
Double: -9,223,372,036,854,780,000, as Int: nil
Double: -∞, as Int: nil
```

Comment: @Alexander The precision is still lost. There is no bijection between the integer values in `Int.min...Int.max` and their images using either Float or Double. (rot13: Abg fher jul guvf tbg qbjaibgrq)

Comment: @MartinR Intentionally. "but I'm still writing this in order to teach what's going on "under the hood."

Comment: @ielyamani Yeah, this code does some truncating towards 0 (as the `0.6`, `0.5`, `0.4` test cases show), but it does prevent out initializing integers from out-of-range-doubles.

Answer (score 0):

I think `nil` would be the appropriate return value of the conversion of `Float.nan`, `Float.infinity`, or outside the range `Int.min...Int.max`.

You could define a range in which the floating number should be included :

```
let validRange: ClosedRange<Float> = Float(Int.min)...Float(Int.max)
```

And use it like so :

```
func convert(_ f: Float) -> Int? {
    var optInteger: Int? = nil

    if  validRange.contains(f) {
        optInteger = Int(f)
    }

    return optInteger
}

print(convert(1.2))  //Optional(1)
```

You should take into consideration that the conversion between `Float` and `Int` loses precision with big values because of the limitation of the number of bits given to each type. For example, using @MartinR's `Int.init(exactly:)` isn't precise enough :

```
let x: Float = 9223371487098961919.0
if let i = Int(exactly: x.rounded()) {
    print(i) 
}
```

yields

> 9223371487098961920

A possible solution would be to use a more precise type. For example `Float80` :

```
let validRange: ClosedRange<Float80> = Float80(Int.min)...Float80(Int.max)

func convert(_ f80: Float80) -> Int? {
    var optInteger: Int? = nil

    if  validRange.contains(f80) {
        optInteger = Int(f80)
    }

    return optInteger
}
```

Here are some use cases:

```
convert(Float80(Int.max))        //Optional(9223372036854775807)
convert(Float80(Int.max) - 1.0)  //Optional(9223372036854775806)
convert(Float80(Int.max) + 1.0)  //nil
convert(Float80(Int.min)))       //Optional(-9223372036854775808)
convert(Float80(Int.min) - 1.0)) //nil
convert(Float80.infinity)        //nil
convert(Float80.nan)             //nil
```

Comment: This essentially forces you to use `Float80` because the first code simply won't work for `Float` or `Double`. `Float(Int.max)` is `9,223,372,036,854,780,000`, which is `4193` more than `Int.max` (`9,223,372,036,854,775,807`), which means that there are `4193` positive integral values for which the `contains` check will succeed, by the integer conversion will crash.

Comment: The conversion of `9223371487098961919.0` to an Int does not lose precision because `Float` (or `Double`) does not have that precision in the first place: `print(9223371487098961919.0 - 9223371487098961920.0) // 0`

Comment: @MartinR your comment is basically mentioned in the answer: 9223371487098961919 was chosen on purpose

Comment: @Alexander moving to Float80 was the logical deduction in the answer. In a previous edit, you’ll see an example of an error of what you’re saying.

Comment: If you're going the `Float80` route, then I would keep it internal to the API (take a parameter of type `Double`, and do a `Float80(d)` internally). Better yet, you can solve this problem using only `Double`. See my answer